# Access Pointer Parameter in Planeshift Source Code

Tags: c++, parameters, parameter-passing, function-calls, function-call

In the file "charmessages.cpp" of Planeshift's source code, the following function is defined:

```
psCharUploadMessage::ToString(NetBase::AccessPointers* accessPointers)
```

http://www.vaikene.net/planeshift/api/classpsCharUploadMessage.html#a1e6ccdcdc6ca383e2c45931d3acb0307

However, there are no examples demonstrating how to call it, or any of the other "ToString(NetBase::AccessPointers* accessPointers)" functions.  What is the proper syntax for the access pointer parameter when calling this function?

Comment: What kind of example did you have in mind? You pass it a pointer of the appropriate type. The syntax is the same as for all member functions. Perhaps you're looking for one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: I have tried, for example, psCharUploadMessage::ToString(&msg), psCharUploadMessage::ToString(msg*), psCharUploadMessage::ToString(msg), psCharUploadMessage.ToString(&msg [and msg* and msg]), msg.ToString(), and similar attempts.